# Как теперь реализовано графическое редактирование `layout`?

Tags: android, android-studio

Забросил студию на полгода, теперь скачал свежую версию и ничего понять не могу. Теперь в шаблонах используются `CustomView`, и в такой `layout` я ничего не могу добавить. Научите чайника как теперь реализовано графическое редактирование `layout`? Т.е. теперь нельзя перетащить Вьюшки на макет, а только в отдельный `layout` и подцепить `include`, но это очень не удобно и руки связывает.

Comment: Сделайте свой макет, какой вам надо с нуля.

Comment: Лучше вообще не юзать графическое редактирование. Оно работает непредсказуемо при различных нюансах. Только `xml`, только хардкор!

Comment: Хардкор это конечно хорошо, Но всё же - как-то можно пользоваться этими шаблонами??

Comment: Попробую повторить - если вам не нравится макет из шаблона, сделайте свой - какой нравится. По вашему описанию вообще ничего не понятно, что у вас не получается и почему. Никаких отличий в работе визуального редактора не произошло, с момента первой беты и до самой последней экспериментальной версии на канале обновлений *canary chanel*

Comment: Ну хорошо, не буду спорить, я так то нуб )
Но насколько помню, раньше основа шаблонов была - RelativeLayout и сразу можно было гибко редактировать любой шаблон, а сейчас они из CustomView состоят, я о них ничего не знаю.

Подскажите где почитать как правильно свои шаблоны делать - буду благодарен!

Comment: Читайте здесь http://m.habrahabr.ru/post/265119/ На первый взгляд это сложно, но я уверен что вам понравится. Некоторые моменты даже легче чем раньше.

Comment: Какой шаблон вы используете. В какой именно `CustomView` вы пытаетесь добавить свои виджеты? Сделать свою разметку: Правый клик на папке `layout` - New -> Layout resource file. Пишите имя и выбираете корневой layout. Потом указываете придуманное имя в методе `setContentView()` той активити, для которой разметка

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В самом визуальном редакторе не произошло никаких изменений, которые могли бы привести к таким "проблемам" в общем случае его использования, однако есть нюансы в его работе.

Подобные затруднения появились у вас, во первых, потому, что вы не до конца понимаете структуру разметки в последних дефолтных шаблонах, предложенных Google.

Разметка `activity_main.xml` в рамках этого шаблона не предназначена для размещения пользовательских виджетов, она служит корневым контейнером и реализует только анимированное взаимодействие `FAB` и `Snakbar` - необходимые вам виджеты, контент и прочее, что вы считаете нужным отобразить на экране, по задумке Google, следует размещать в разметке `fragment_main.xml`,что в общем то перекрывает 99% нужд любителей писать приложения с использованием шаблонов.

Во вторых, сам "глюк" по поводу того, что нельзя "кинуть" виджет в визуальном редакторе исходит из того, что по мнению этого визуального редактора, разметка `activity_main.xml` в данном шаблоне не содержит контейнеров, которые могли бы разместить в себе виджеты. Точнее `CoordinatorLayout` по сути является `FrameLayout` и , конечно, может содержать в себе виджеты, но визуальный редактор пока не в состоянии определить это для контейнеров, которые не являются базовыми (CustomView). Будем надеяться, что когда-нибудь это будет исправлено, а пока, если редактировать именно `activity_main.xml` вам очень уж хочется, несмотря на юзкейс, предложенный Google, есть такие варианты:

1. вы можете решить эту проблему радикально, создавая свою собственную разметку.
   Кликните правой кнопкой мыши на папке `res/layout` и проследуйте *New -> Layout resource file*. Появится мастер создания новой разметки, где вам необходимо указать ее имя и корневой контейнер, например `LinearLayout`. Далее вы сможете работать с этой разметкой в так полюбившемся вам визуальном редакторе.
2. Вы можете добавить какой-либо базовый контейнер в режиме ручного редактирования (Text). Например, заменив вызов фрагмента (`include @layout/content_main`) на какой-нибудь `LinearLayout`. После этого вы сможете "кидать" туда виджеты в визуальном редакторе
3. Вы можете выдохнуть и отказаться от использования визуального редактора, который в основном бесполезен и местами даже вреден и создавать разметку в режиме ручного редактирования (Text), визуальный редактор используя только для просмотра результата. Тогда вы сможете добавить что угодно и куда угодно, в ответ максимум, что вас ждет, это ваше приложение не соберется во что то работающее.

Comment: Третий пункт верен на 100%)